# How to clone parent SObject to child SObjects with field restriction

Tags: apex, clone

I have a requirement where I have to `clone` a parent `Product2` to all of it's child `Product2s`.

I know we can achieve this by using `clone()` function of `Product2`, but I want some `field` values should not pass from parent `Product` to child `products`.

Is there any workaround for this requirement ?

Comment: What do you mean by `clone()` function on `Product2` - do yo mean the Clone UI button? or the sObject class instance method `clone(..)`?

Answer (score 0):

@Surendranadh's answer is actually just portion of the solution.

What you can do is to create a field set that would contain all of the fields that you want to be copied over the child products.

Then you can reference the created fieldset on a trigger(assuming this is on a trigger context) to populate the selected fields on the child products.

Here's a sample snippet below that you can use to achieve this:

```
//Retrieve all Parent Products,
List<Product2> parentProducts = [SELECT Id, <List of Fields> FROM Product2 WHERE <Parent Products Query>];

//Retrieve created fieldset
List<Schema.FieldSetMember> productCloneFieldSet = SObjectType.Product2.FieldSets.<FieldSet_Name>.getFields();

List<String> fieldAPIs = new List<String>();
//Retrieve each Field API 
for(FieldSetMember fsm : productCloneFieldSet) {
    fieldAPIs.add(fsm.getFieldPath());
}

List<Product2> chldProdList = new List<Product2>();
for(Product2 parent: parentProducts) {
    Product2 chldProd = new Product2();
    //Iterate through field set API, then populate child fields using put
    for(String strAPI : fieldAPIs){
        chldProd.put(strAPI,parent.get(strAPI));
    }
    childInsert.add(chldProd);
}

//Insert all child product
insert chldProdList;
```

**NOTE: ** My code just assumes that I'll be cloning the parent product record. If the values needs to be copied over to all child product records, you need to query all of the child products first then iterate through it to populate the fields specified on your field set.

You can refer to this link on working with fieldsets : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_dynamic_vf_field_sets.htm